# Using appleDoc and ///TODO: comment

Tags: ios, xcode, todo, appledoc

I'm working on a project that uses AppleDoc to generate documentation. I want to add some TODO comments in my code eg:

```
///TODO: Some stuff to be done
-(void)myMethod:(id)myParam{
  [self doSomeFancyStuff];
}
```

The problem is that when I try to generate my project doc I get theses troublesome warnings :

> /Users/Me/trunk/MyProject/MyProject/src/MyClass.m:119:
>   MyClass.m@119: Description for parameter 'myParam'
>   missing for -[MyClass
>   myMethod:]

Obviously I could get rid of my TODO comments but I'd like to keep them along with my beautyful doc. Does anybody know how to achieve that ?

Comment: Did you try to use `//TODO:` instead of `///TODO:`?

Comment: I expect it's complaining because you aren't documenting the parameter, which has nothing to do with the `TODO` comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `///` block, you trigger an Appledoc/Doxygen documentation block and the function is marked as documented. The doc generator will check and report that block as incomplete because you did not document the parameter.

You have 2 solutions:

1. add another row with `/// @param myParam brief explanation of what it is`
2. use `//` instead of `///`.

Comment: Ok I don't know why I was sure it needed 3 slashes...
Anyway thank you